# Thunder Client Response page is showing blank/null

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, backend

Whenever I try to run this in thunder client is showing blank/null response page. expect this everything is working great.
Can anyone help me.
Maybe some coding mistake.

[Router code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcI68.png)

[thunder client response page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q70KS.png)

[fetch-user code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F449V.png)

I tried to find the solution in YOUTUBE and STACKOVERFLOW.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
http://localhost:5000/api/auth/getuser
```

instead of just

```
localhost:5000/api/auth/getuser
```

have you added this line in the app.js file

```
app.use(express.json)
```

Comment: used http://localhost:5000/api/auth/getuser in thunder client but its showing 404 bad request

Comment: for app.js I'm currently working in backend in mongo/express and testing in thunder client